# Connect Laravel with vertica Database

Tags: php, database, laravel, vertica

I have problems linking my Project to my database. I want to select stuff from a vertica database into my project. In normal PHP it works, but the same code does not work in Laravel:

```
# Connect to the Database
$dsn = "VerticaDSN";
$conn = odbc_connect($dsn,'','') or die ("<br/>CONNECTION ERROR");
echo "<p>Connected with DSN: $dsn</p>";

# Get the data from the table and display it
$sql = "SELECT column FROM table";
if($result = errortrap_odbc($conn, $sql))
{
    echo "<pre>";
    while($row = odbc_fetch_array($result) )
    {
        echo "hi";
        print_r($row);
    }
    echo "</pre>";
}
```

Is there a method that this code works inside my Laravel Controller?

Comment: read the docs https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/database

Comment: I read them, but there is no support for vertica database, thats my problem

Comment: write the code yourself then if it doesn't exist or search the web for it ;-)

Answer (score 1):

What exact error have you? Is your `$dns` correct? It must look like:

```
$dsn = 'Driver=Vertica;Servername=xxx;Port=5433;Database=yyy';
odbc_connect($dsn,'usr','pwd');
```

In my [Github repository](https://github.com/mixartemev/dbal-vertica-driver) there are detailed instructions for the use of Vertica in Laravel.